# Nomenclature of complexes: Cyano vs Cyanido ; Chloro vs Chlorido

Tags: nomenclature, coordination-compounds

What is the correct nomenclature for $\ce{CN^-}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ ligands in coordination compounds?

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_complex#Naming_complexes) says the coding name(?) as cyanido and chlorido while [this](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Coordination_Chemistry/Basics_of_Coordination_Chemistry/Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Complexes#Rules_for_Naming_the_Ligands) suggests cyano and chloro.

Comment: Maybe the website that says chloro was created before 2006 and then wasnt updated. Thank you.

Comment: It was also cyano over [here](http://www.chemistry.wustl.edu/~edudev/LabTutorials/naming_coord_comp.html). but I couldn't add more links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [IUPAC Red Book](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf) is the official reference for recommended inorganic nomenclature. The full change to the additive nomenclature system was made in the 2005 update:

> Some new recommendations represent breaks with tradition, in the interest of increased clarity and consistency. For example, the application of the ending ‘ido’ to all anionic ligands with ‘ide’ names in additive nomenclature (e.g. chlorido and cyanido instead of chloro and cyano, and hydrido throughout, i.e. no exception in boron nomenclature) is part of a general move to a more systematic approach.

This is discussed in more detail in section IR-7.1.3 on page 112. Basically, anionic ligand names used as prefixes get changed from '-ide', '-ate', and '-ite' to '-ido', '-ato', and 'ito', respectively. Neutral and cationic ligands are usually used unchanged except for things like aqua, ammine, carbonyl, etc.

Comment: Official answer.  The "aMMine" part is one to keep in mind as I get confused between it and aMine. Thank you.